# Wildcard routes not working on opeshift 4.x

Tags: kubernetes, routes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

It seems I cannot use wildcard routes on openshift 4.x
It was supposed to work on prior versions though.
https://github.com/debianmaster/openshift-examples/tree/master/wildcard-on-route

Does anyone know how to do it on Openshift 4.x?

I'm getting a message saying wildcard routes are not allowed from the openshift console.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard routes are not yet supported under OCP 4.x [1].
Thee procedure linked in the github repo has no chance to work. OCP 4 has a different configuration mechanism based on operators. Routers are generated by an operator in another namespace (eg: openshift-ingress).

[1] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1713414